# Codename One Map

Tags: java, dictionary, components, codenameone

I  want to display a map with some coordinates, I can do it on one GUI Element, but when I duplicate the code for other GUI Element the map doesn't appear

This is the code for one GUI Element (page or screen)

```
@Override
protected void beforeMapaGPS(Form f) {
    MapComponent mapComponent= new MapComponent();
    double latitude=-41.169782;
    double longitude =-71.444885;

    Coord lastLocation = new Coord(latitude, longitude);
    mapComponent.zoomTo(lastLocation, 15);


    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.addComponent(mapComponent);
    f.show();
}
```

and this is the other GUI Element (other page or screen) is copied from the first

```
@Override
protected void onCreateGUI1() {
 MapComponent mapComponent= new MapComponent();
    double latitude=-41.169782;
    double longitude =-71.444885;

    Coord lastLocation = new Coord(latitude, longitude);
    mapComponent.zoomTo(lastLocation, 15);


    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.addComponent(mapComponent);
    f.show();
}
```

when I run the simulator the map appear on the first page or screen, and not on the other

Message received when I save the designer

[image]

Comment: The answer from @diamond is correct. I also suggest inspecting your UI to make sure that you don't have GUI elements there that are interfering with your map e.g. another map... I would also suggest setting a breakpoint in the code to verify the before* call is reached.

Comment: Not really, the GUI elements are empty, on both screen

Comment: I a not sure is related, but I do this: I duplicate the GUI element , add the before show action and when I save I receive a warning related to images(I added it to the post), at the same time the @Overrride still on Statemachine.java in red, is not added to the sateachineBase, even when i save the file several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use FlowLayout for any peer component or complex components like Map, Browser, List, Multi-list...

Secondly, you are implementing the Map code in the `onCreate` method for the second form. Do it inside `beforeShow()` or `postShow()` methods.

And lastly, you are requesting a form that's already showing to show again by calling `f.show()` inside a `beforeShow()` method.

Change your code to:

```
@Override
protected void beforeMapaGPS(Form f) {
    MapComponent mapComponent= new MapComponent();
    double latitude=-41.169782;
    double longitude =-71.444885;

    Coord lastLocation = new Coord(latitude, longitude);
    mapComponent.zoomTo(lastLocation, 15);

    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mapComponent);
}
```

and the second one to:

```
@Override
protected void beforeGUI1(Form f) {
    MapComponent mapComponent= new MapComponent();
    double latitude=-41.169782;
    double longitude =-71.444885;

    Coord lastLocation = new Coord(latitude, longitude);
    mapComponent.zoomTo(lastLocation, 15);

    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mapComponent);
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. I added (Form f) to the second protected void beforeGUI(), then run the simulator and there is no map on the second screen.

Comment: I tried as you wrote and the receive message  cannot find  symbol, variable f

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I wanted to write. FYI you shouldn't use `revalidate` in a before* callback as it is implicit and would cause duplicate work.

Comment: @Diamond you were right, apparently the issue was related to my IO error!!!!! Thanks!